# R: Unexpected cropping in mfrow graph

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to create a 3x3 multiplot with mfrow. The layout is correct, however the single plots seem to contain only part of the data. The code I use to produce the graph is

```
timing = c(10,30,50,75,100,125,200,250,300)

pdf("Figure.pdf")
par(mfrow=c(3,3))
for(t in timing) {
 dat = subset(inventory.data,Time==t)
 plot(NA, xlim=c(0,200),ylim=c(0,200), xlab = NA, ylab = NA, main =  paste("Time",t))
 points(x = dat$X, y = dat$Y, pch = 21, cex = dat$CD)
}
dev.off()
```

which gives

[image]

However if I plot the graphs one by one with the same script, the range is much larger. For example for "Time 300" the original plot is

[image]

In the mfrow plots only the region around coordinates (160, 70) are plotted and much of the graph is cropped.

How do I get all the single plot regions inside?

Comment: Please post the `dput` of *inventory.data* for reproducible example. Does the one plot use subset data or full data? Is *Time 10* graph correctly rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually not a cropping problem, but rather a scaling problem. The region being plotted in both graphs is (0,200)x(0,200). However, there is so much overlap in both that the defined circles that you can see are the simply the last ones being plotted. Clearly the concentric blue and green circles around (190, 60) is the easiest shared feature to identify in the two plots. But let's look at some more:

- Dark green circle at (70, 180)
- Light green circle at (47, 2)
- Blue circle at (110, 140)
- Blue circle at (190, 160)

What appears to be happening here is that you've taken a plot and forced it into an area less than 1/9 the size of the original area, but you haven't scaled the actual elements of the graph any differently. You either need to increase the size of the PDF or decrease the size of the circles in order to make it readable. Here's a short reproducible example. In the future (especially if the question is important enough to bounty), providing a reproducible example (like using `dput` as commented by Parfait) helps a ton.

```r
dat <- data.frame(x = runif(9*100)*200,
                  y = runif(9*100)*200,
                  size = rpois(9*100, 5)+1,
                  col = rbinom(9*100, 1, .1),
                  group = rep(1:9, 100))

set.seed(1011)

make_plot <- function(d, t, adjust = 1) {
  plot(NA, xlim=c(0,200),ylim=c(0,200), xlab = NA, ylab = NA, main =  paste("Time",t))
  sub_d <- dat[dat$group == t,]
  points(x = sub_d$x[sub_d$col == 0], y = sub_d$y[sub_d$col == 0], 
         cex = sub_d$size[sub_d$col == 0]/adjust, pch = 16, col = rgb(0,1,0,.25))
  points(x = sub_d$x[sub_d$col == 0], y = sub_d$y[sub_d$col == 0], 
         cex = sub_d$size[sub_d$col == 0]/adjust, pch = 21, col = rgb(0,1,0,.5), lwd = 2)
  points(x = sub_d$x[sub_d$col == 1], y = sub_d$y[sub_d$col == 1], 
         cex = sub_d$size[sub_d$col == 1]/adjust, pch = 16, col = rgb(0,0,1,.25))
  points(x = sub_d$x[sub_d$col == 1], y = sub_d$y[sub_d$col == 1], 
         cex = sub_d$size[sub_d$col == 1]/adjust, pch = 21, col = rgb(0,0,1,.5), lwd = 2)
}

## Big plot
t = 1
plot(-50, -50, xlim=c(0,200),ylim=c(0,200), xlab = NA, ylab = NA, main =  paste("Time",t))
sub_d <- dat[dat$group == t,]
points(x = sub_d$x[sub_d$col == 0], y = sub_d$y[sub_d$col == 0], 
       cex = sub_d$size[sub_d$col == 0], pch = 16, col = rgb(0,1,0,.25))
points(x = sub_d$x[sub_d$col == 0], y = sub_d$y[sub_d$col == 0], 
       cex = sub_d$size[sub_d$col == 0], pch = 21, col = rgb(0,1,0,.5), lwd = 2)
points(x = sub_d$x[sub_d$col == 1], y = sub_d$y[sub_d$col == 1], 
       cex = sub_d$size[sub_d$col == 1], pch = 16, col = rgb(0,0,1,.25))
points(x = sub_d$x[sub_d$col == 1], y = sub_d$y[sub_d$col == 1], 
       cex = sub_d$size[sub_d$col == 1], pch = 21, col = rgb(0,0,1,.5), lwd = 2)
```

[image]

```r
## Wrong for scale
par(mfrow=c(3,3))
for(t in 1:9) {
  make_plot(dat, t)
}
```

[image]

```r
## Slightly better scale
par(mfrow=c(3,3))
for(t in 1:9) {
  make_plot(dat, t, adjust = 3)
}
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-09-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Ok this already helps. By reducing the cex.points I am able to fit them inside the plot region. But what should the exact cex be? I mean in my data I have cex = dat$CD which is an actual measurement of a diameter. So in other words if I have dat$CD = 20 that should be a point with diameter 20 in the graphs...

Comment: The `cex` argument is 'character expansion'. It's all relative to the size of a point on a graph by default (`cex = 2` means that the point will be twice as large as the default). It would be extremely hard to use that argument to try to set absolute sizes as any time the resolution or file size changes, you'd have to find the new correct value for it. Instead you should look into plotting circles. I don't have much experience here but you could check out `filledcircle()` from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shape/shape.pdf as a starting point.